# Como hago para separar una direccion con str.split despues de que aparezca los numeros de las casas en una sola columna?

Tags: python, regex, split

Hola tengo un excel donde esta las direcciones con numeros pisos y dpt y quiero separarla en una columna despues del numero de la casa/dpt, el problema esta que por ejemplo puedo tener nombres de calles que empiezan con un numero por ejemplo 27 de febrero.

Este es un ejemplo BUENOS AIRES 1477 Piso 00 Dto.01 y me gustaria que quede asi:

| calles | direccion |
| --- | --- |
| BUENOS AIRES | 1477 Piso 00 Dto.01 |
| 27 DE FEBRERO | 2354 |

Agregue otro ejemplo para que vean cuando empieza con un numero de una sola cifra.
intente usar Str.split pero me tira tambien el error "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key". se que tengo que usar expresiones regulares pero me esta costando.
Gracias por adelantado

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```py
clientes[['numeros']] = clientes['Dom.Comercial'].str.split(r"(\S\w\d\d|\S\w\d|\d)",n=1,expand=false)
print (clientes)
```

[image: dos marionetas]

Les dejo un google sheets si quieren ver como son las direcciones
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OXPsaamuiUsHkF_qRqU-HZkr45-5ED2wOjGOUE9GiJs/edit?usp=sharing

Lllegue a que me reconzca los numeros despues de las calles, hasta cuando tiene un numero, el problema menor lo tengo con las calles que todavia no tienen nombre oficial y tienen por nombre "CALLE" (son los menos), que despues lo podria solucionar, pero supongo que con alguna excepcion se tiene que arreglar. esto buscando un comando REGEX que despues de esos numeros me agarre todo lo que sigue pero no se cual seria

me hizo la separacion pero le tuve que poner el expand=false porque si no me tira error

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131846/discussion-on-question-by-matias-poses-como-hago-para-separar-una-direccion-con).